# How would you make an edge circle around a cone?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I tried using the knife tool, which turned out to be a disaster since I have partially paralyzed hands.  I tried loop slide and whatever and it appeared to not do anything.  I tried subdivide and got something I think I can work with but there has to be an easier way.  Can anyone give me a hint or a link to a good basic tips tutorial or anything?

Comment: The core of the issue is that a cone is made out of triangles. Loop cuts only work with quads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sure it must be difficult to be unable to do traditional art after having done it for so long. :-/ Great that you're learning 3D though!

Edge looping cones is a bit tricky. The easiest method that I know of is to do this:

1. Select the bottom edge
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the bottom edge
3. Select the higher of the two bottom edges, and hit <kbd>G</kbd> twice to enter edge slide mode. Slide into place.

Here's an image to help.

[image: Steps to add an edge loop to a cone.]

Honestly, I would recommend sliding your first edge loop all the way to the top, then deleting everything above it--so that the very top of your cone is actually a tiny edge ring. You can then use <kbd>F</kbd> to fill it to cap it off. This'll make it so that you can use the regular edge loop tool to create edge loops in the future.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so very much!  I actually get the answer!!!!  Is there any way to give you some site creds for helping an old man out?  :-)

Comment: Haha, no need for anything extra. Glad to help!

Comment: I would like to add that if creating a new objet from scratch is an option, I would instead start from a cylinder, like in this example : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39290/58271
It's a little bit more straightforward and easy to understand than the bevel / edge slide trick I think.