# Why can't I loop cut a cone?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

Why can't I loop cut a cone? I started a new file, created a cone and did nothing but try to loop cut it, and it didn't work.

Comment: Non manifold geometry. You can only loop cut quads, and a cone is made of triangles

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35581/how-would-you-make-an-edge-circle-around-a-cone/35582#35582

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In layman terms loop cut will only work on geometry with 'clear edge flow' meaning in most if not all cases you should ideally be able to look at it and tell where the cut will go or it should divide your mesh equally into more sections that can be cut again. So it won't work for triangles (3 vertices) or ngons (mesh with more than 4 vertices), [What is non-manifold geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry). There is a simple work around however. Create a cone by adding a cylinder and scaling the top as small as possible without actually letting the vertices overlap, when zoomed out, this is unnoticeable.

[image]

Comment: Once you're finished, it is helpful to remove doubles to keep your vertex count and processing load down.