# How can I make a kind of napkin (twirl, pleating, vortex) whirl kind of extrude effect?

Tags: modeling

At its simplest it's like twirling a napkin or piece of paper from the center where alternate edges rise.

If a picture's worth 1000 words, this kind of effect:

[image]

There's already a flat spiral example here:

[How can I make a flat, spiralled surface?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42674/how-can-i-make-a-flat-spiralled-surface)

As I'm envisioning it, for example, the red twirls would be raised.

I've seen comparable examples on cylinders, but not on surfaces (square or circular) - like a pleated dress for example, or a curly cone, but not a flat surface.

Is that enough info?

Tried simple deform and proportional editing, but I keep missing the mark.  Maybe they're key to the result or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At its simplest, this is a selection problem.

- Create mesh Circle, 'Triangle-Fan', with an even number of segments, in XY.
- Select the central vertex, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> - drag Bevel it, to make all faces quads.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut in some subdivisions of the radial edges, as below.

[image]

- Using <kbd>O</kbd>, Proportional Editing, select the central face, and <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> rotate it, which should drag all the other vertices in the radius of your prop. edit into a spiral.
- Select 2 sections of radial edges, in the same ring, 1 edge apart, as just visible in the central image, below.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> Select Next Active, to select every other radial edge in 1 ring.
- Header Menu > *Select* > *Select Loops* > *Select Edge Loops* to select every other radial edge, as show in the last picture, below.

[image]

Now you can <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.. raise, tuck the pleats.

[image]

If you wanted to, using a similar selection method to the one used for the spokes, you could select every other edge-ring, to delete those. Or, think ahead, and delete them before all the twisting, etc.

The finished example, here, has a *Solidify* and *Bevel* modifier.

Comment: "Select 2 spoke sections at the same radius, 1 spoke apart" is confusing to me, please clarify.

Comment: This method works with the example, but, doesn't seem to work as well with a less circular shape like a square, polygon, or hexagon.  I know that's not what I asked for.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-B doesn't seem to work for me.  I must be doing something wrong. I get a gloopy mess.  Doesn't matter whether I choose percent, width, offset, any of the options - same result.

Comment: Found this that helped with "Ctrl-Shift-B:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39512/how-to-divide-a-circle-into-slices-for-each-side

Comment: Under O rotate the central face is also confusing.  There's no explicit "rotate the central face" option.

Comment: I got to what you had in mind by selecting the center vertex, extending rotation to the whole object and rotating the z-axis - double tap.  Probably useful to remember to turn off proportional editing before G-Z, R-Z the edges.

Comment: What worked for me:

 - Create mesh Circle, ‘Triangle-Fan’, Default 32 

- Ctrl Shift B Instead I used:

- Circle select all the edges, Esc out of Circle select and W - Subdivide max, (10) twice

- Use O to turn on proportional editing

Select the Central Vertex

R to rotate, scroll  (wheel on the mouse) to select the whole cirlce, Double tap Z to rotate

Select Alternate edges, I used Shift-Alt to select each in turn

Then G-Z, R-Z to rais and rotate

(Extra:  E, Edge Crease -1, Bevel Edges: .03, 3 segments, then smooth corrective and subdivide)

Think that's everything.

Comment: When I typed that all in it was a lot cleaner.  StackExchange limitations - my apologies.

Comment: My Blend file - more legible instructions included:  https://pasteall.org/blend/2faf4c58695d4f8ca4f3f3cd20d760bf

Good for 6 months. (Pasteall rules)

Comment: Hi @unkerjay! Phew!  Had to be AFK... I'm sorry I'm being so unclear.. do you have editing privileges? If so, feel free.. I can't really answer all this in the comments.. I'll take what I can from your .blend

Comment: I've tried to improve it, a bit.

Comment: As with all things Blender, there's more than one way to do it.  I'm just applying what I've learned.  You provided the template.  So, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would try it like this:
[image]

create a circle, use twice as many points you will need and then press F3 and find "checker" use this option, it will deselect every second vert

[image]

Then you can use E and S to extrude it to middle

[image]

Next you want to subdivide your edges as much as possible

Now use proportional editing , select middle vertices and rotate it around Z axis to make spiral:
[image]

[image]

and now you want to Extrude all vertices you want to be solid like in picture, extrude with E and rotate around Z axis till you get your shape... After that it is only about rotating and moving vertices... I ended up with this and I think it is usable:

[image]

Comment: Yours is easier to follow and I think, simple, but Robin's is closer to spot on to the example.